# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{x^3-8}{x^2-x-2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I've done so many limit problems in calculus lately, but I can't wrap my mind around how to simplify this one in order to solve it:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \dfrac{x^3-8}{x^2-x-2} 
$$

I understand the $x^3-8$ factors down to $(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$, but that still leaves us with
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \dfrac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{x^2-x-2}, 
$$
which I can't seem to find a way to simplify so that the denominator is not equal to 0.

In case anyone figures out themselves, the answer is 4 (I was given the answer - this is on a review sheet for an upcoming exam).  Also, I tagged this as homework, even though it is not technically homework.

So if anyone could help point me in the right direction here, that would be very helpful.

Comment: The denominator factors as $x^2-x-2 = (x-2)(x+1)$. Does that help?

Comment: If you plug $2$ into a polynomial and get $0$, then $x-2$ is one of its factors.  That's worth knowing.  And if you plug $2$ in and get something other than $0$, then you won't get a $0$ in the denominator in a case like this, so then you could just plug $2$ into the whole expression and that's the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x+1)$.

Comment: And theres my answer.. I didn't even think that the denominator was factorable! How could I have missed that.  Thank you - I will approve your answer when the time limit for which I can't approve any answer is up.

Comment: @Mike: If $p(x)$ is a polynomial, and $p(a)=0$, then $p(x)$ can **always** be factored as $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. This is the [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_Theorem), so with these kinds of limits (a rational function that evaluates to $\frac{0}{0}$), you can *always* factor both the numerator and the denominator, cancel the factor, and try again.

Comment: Oh okay.  That's sensible.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{x^3-8}{x^2-x-2}=\lim_{x \to 2}\dfrac{(x^3-8)'}{(x^2-x-2)'}=...$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the L`Hospital rule to find the answer. [image: L´Hospital Rule]

Comment: Why this late answer to a question with an accepted answer? And it's not like your answer is much better than the previous answers either.